# Is there a better way to connect two JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

[**NetBeans Project** and **Source Code** of a minimal example](https://mega.co.nz/#!HdAFXZSA!v3WkHTf5n8VP4IEj3pag1uf3JEIXi3Tz1vXQdTME4Bo)

Is there a better way to connect a `JFrame` with a `JPanel` from another class other than making the fields of the `JPanel` public?

I am writing a program where there is going to be an option button, when that button is pressed a custom `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` will be brought up with a `JPanel` inside it which will hold the specific options that the user wants.

When the user presses the `JOptionPane.OK_OPTION` button the program closes the `OptionDialog` with the `JPanel` inside it and returns to the `JFrame`. Then I need whatever was inputted in the JPanel to be used in the `JFrame` class. I did that by just making the text fields of the `JPanel` public but I feel like this is a cheap way of doing it especially since `NetBeans` would not let me do that unless I opened the source in a notepad.

**Also I would be totally ok with if the `JOptionPane.OK_OPTION` was just saving the fields of the `Jpanel` in a file and then I could separately retrieve them in the `JFrame` class.**

So is there a better way to do this?

**`JFrame` action listener:**

```
private void goSettingsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        Settings settings = new Settings();
        int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                settings,
                "Settings",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                null,
                new String[]{"Save", "Cancel"},
                "default");
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            username = settings.jTextField1.getText();
            usernameInputedLabel.setText(username);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a specific example of a general question: how do two objects communicate?

- Your consideration of using a public field as you know is wrong.
- You mention saving data to a file, but isn't that over-kill, and won't that add needless time and resource overhead when a much simpler solution is available?
- Better to just use the same technique that you'd use if this were not a Swing GUI: public methods including getter and setter methods if need be.

e.g.,

```
private void goSettingsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            settings,
            "Settings",
            JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
            null,
            new String[]{"Save", "Cancel"},
            "default");
    if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {

        // **** give your Settings class this method:
        username = settings.getUserName(); 
        usernameInputedLabel.setText(username);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> I would have used getters and setters but from the books that I've read and the forums that I frequent I know that the general consensus is that having getters and setters is even worse than public fields.

Sorry, but that's hogwash. Please consider your code vs. my code. In my code above, I suggest givng Settings a method, something like:

```
// in declarations:
// don't name this jTextField1
private JTextField userNameField = new JTextField();

// public getter method
public String getUserName() {
   return jTextField1.getText(); // this should be named userNameField
}
```

Whereas your suggestion is to make the JTextField public, fully exposing it to all comers. Which is riskier? Which could allow the calling code to change the state of the Settings object without your knowing about it?

Comment: I would have used getters and setters but from the books that I've read and the forums that I frequent I know that the general consensus is that having getters and setters is even worse than public fields.

Comment: @SilliconTouch: please show me a decent reference on that statement above. You are in essence stating that it's better to fully expose fields rather than use limited and controlled exposure of necessary data, and that's just not true, not at all.

Comment: @SilliconTouch: also, if you have a minimal example, post it here as code for all to see, not as a link that can go stale in the future or carry risk if accessed.

Comment: I was about to edit in that I am talking about C++ mostly and about simple cases where validation is not required. References are the *Accelerated C++* book and from forums I remember reading it in many places (for C++) but it will take too much time to find it. Also I did not want to post a minimal example because it would be a wall of code generated from NetBeans which would not be optimal so I opted to show the part of the code that matters.

Comment: But anyway if setters and getters are indeed viable then I'll just use them, thx.

Comment: @SilliconTouch: think in terms of encapsulation and safety from unknown side effects! Please see edit to answer.

Comment: thank you very much. Now that I think about it it definitely is better to use them.